# How do I grow RAID 1?

Tags: raid, mdadm

When my current 2TB RAID 1 array(with 2 disks) gets full, how can I add more storage? I'm aware that RAID 1 keeps both disks identical, and that I need to replace both. Basically, how can I change disks without losing all my data?